# Exclude a combination involving a branch from GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions

I'd like to exclude certain parts of my build matrix on certain branches. Something conceptually like the following, which doesn't work because `branches` is not a matrix variable.

```yaml
name: Tests

on:
  pull_request:
  push:
    branches: [hackage, develop]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:

        os: [ubuntu-latest]
        resolver: [lts-3.22 , lts-17, lts-18, lts, nightly]
        exclude:
          - branches: [hackage]
            resolver: [nightly, lts]
```

Is there a way to do this idiomatically. [Here, for example](https://github.com/orome/crypto-enigma-hs/blob/develop/.github/workflows/test.yml) to exclude `nightly` and `lts` resolvers on the `hackage` branch?

Comment: Have you tried updating the yaml file in these specific branches with the matrix configuration you want?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? there might be other and cleaner solutions to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` with [`github.ref_name`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) to identify the branch and the [`contains()`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#contains) function to check for `matrix.resolver` for the parts that you want to exclude.

Example:

```yaml
if: github.ref_name == 'hackage' && contains(fromJSON('["nightly", "lts"]'), matrix.resolver)
```

`if` could be for jobs i.e. [`jobs.<job_id>.if`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif) or steps i.e. [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].if`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsif).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the github.ref context to check the current branch and exclude specific elements from the matrix accordingly.

```
name: Tests
    
    on:
      pull_request:
      push:
        branches: [hackage, develop]
    
    jobs:
      build:
        runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
        strategy:
          matrix:
            os: [ubuntu-latest]
            resolver: [lts-3.22 , lts-17, lts-18, lts, nightly]
            exclude:
              - resolver: nightly
                if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/heads/hackage')
              - resolver: lts
                if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/heads/hackage')
```

Comment: Do you have a working example for it? In your workflow, `if` is not part of the `matrix` but it is used under `exclude` so I'm wondering how it even works. See [here](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJylUEFOwzAQvOcVc0AKSEkQ5QDyO5A4oAo5yTY2uHbw2lWrqn/HrgPthROXHa93dnY0Vm5J4IU4cFU5Kypgjsa8e/qK6bP0rDICvZd2UMQCb0oOn3KiBiPtyLh5XVUfrufM66M2Y1nw0XKbVHFzPGIrg9f7zjFOp/OUg5eBpkPhYiH8dIDLh2IfbYitSUwO69+ZJ3ZmRz4xTOD2sVut0CA/H54WfD5jA6snFczhskv7wcSRLoeA9kpw4V9NAb0Rya70gV91ULdTKrHvPG0a1KnyvSI5plpSqe/+kE5+/ie75EYzF/dtjliABuVQ54Tqb8WaiY4=) the linter complaining for the same.